# Rank quality of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for a terminology for what I ignorantly call "*Rank quality of a matrix*". Suppose $A=uv^T$ where $u$ and $v$ are non-zero column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n, n≥2$. Suppose that each eigenvalue $\lambda$ is different than zero, thus $A$ is full rank.

This is where I struggle, since $\lambda>\epsilon$ for such small $\epsilon$ makes $A$ full rank. Is there any term for rank quality for the linear independency of a matrix? I guess, I cannot say that $A$ is *more* linear if each $\lambda>>0$ ?

I hope I made myself clear, I am quite new to topic.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: What is $uvT$ especially $uv$? Are you referring to the dot product of $u$ and $v$? What is $T$? And is the second sentence "Each eigenvalue  $\lambda$ is different than zero" a conclusion you draw from the first or another assumption? I am not quite understanding your definition of "Rank quality of a matrix"

Comment: I'm not sure if I have fully understood the question, but it seems like you might be interested in [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number).

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I've fixed some of the typos. Simply, I am talking about a full-rank matrix $A$. As @antunmagdic pointed out, condition number was the term I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: The way you have defined $A$, it can never be full rank. In fact rank of $A$ will always be equal to $1$.